# Trying to get property of a non-object when instanciating an object (unit testing a controller)

Tags: php, unit-testing

I'm getting an error, "trying to get property of a non-object" when I'm only trying to instantiate a controller in my unit test class.

```
<?php namespace Tests\Unitaires\ModuleFournisseurs;

session_start();

    /**
    * Test du controlleur X
    */
    class XControllerTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
    {
    public function testScenario()
    {
        // loading my modules
        \bootstrapDev::addModules(Array(
            'ModuleX',
            'ModuleY',
            // ...
        ));
        // runing my bootstrap
        \bootstrapDev::init();
        // the line of code that generates the error
        $controlleur = new \Name\Space\XController;

        $this->assertTrue(true);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the source of the error. it was because my controller extends another class that has some treatement in its constructor that generates the error.